# is android possible for develop eap-sim connection via NDK?

Tags: android

on my galaxy ace, i have a problem with wifi eap-sim connection. SSID was detected, but when i try to connect is always failed or disconnected. to make it connect, i'd have to root my phone, but i dont want to root it.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You need -

1. Patch RIL interface to expose GSM Logical Channel.
2. Implemented a Smartcard Service for access to the RIL interface.
3. Patch wpa_supplicant to use the Smart Service
4. patch Wifi setting interface.